# Launch image doesn't update in xcode 4.5 with Cordova 2.1

Tags: xcode, ios6, cordova

I'm using Xcode 4.5, Cordova 2.1 , iPhone4 (IOS6）. Adding launch image is pretty simple -- just drag the image to the Project->Summary->Launch Images window.

So I set a launch image before and it worked. But when I dragged a different image and run the app on my iPhone again, the launch image still remain the same as the old one. Even after I delete the launch image from the Launch Images window, the old image still shows up upon launching.

I've tried clearing the build as well. And I have try to delete the app in my devices.In the simulator it works well.But in my iPhone4(with ios6) it doesn't.I have tried this again and again.But I can't find the solution.

In before,I often use my images to change the default launch images in the folder.But this time,it doesn't work.

Does anybody know the solution of this problem?

Answer (score 7):

You have to change these images in your project

```
Splash/Default@2x~iphone
Splash/Default~iphone
```

Either be sure to have the option of splash screen in Cordova.plist, AutoHideSplashScreen to YES.

But putting my images in the right format works fine.
For me it display firstly an image full screen, and then the image of splash directory.

Comment: thanks man,but this doesn't help me.And I solve this problem in another way.I will post another answer here tomorrow.But,thank you again.And maybe this answer would help other people.!:-)

Comment: Thanks a lot this totally solved the problem. It is strange why uploading the icons/splash screens in the summary doesnt replace the images in the Resources directory...

Answer (score 1):

"The launch image remains the same as the old one" - this is unfortunately not a Cordova thing, there's just something screwy going on with Xcode and your device. Try rebooting it. For the Simulator, sometimes it fixed it for people once they Reset the simulator as well.

Comment: Thx.I had tried it again and again.But it doesn't work.Finally,I add "Launch Image" into plist and add an image into the folder and edit CDVViewController.m.It becomes well.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solve this problem by myself.Follow these steps and hope that you would success.

1,Prepare your image files and add into the project folder.Remember that you should use xcode to add your files in to the Group.

2,Edit your info.plist file.Add a key -> "Launch Image" ,  Value -> "[Your File name]"; key -> "Launch Image (iPhone)" -> "[Your File Name]";

Try to test your project.If it doesn't work,you should edit your CDVViewController.m.(It is in the CordovaLib(Cordova Lib -> Classes -> Cleaver -> CDVViewController.m ).

3,Replace "Default" as your File name in CDVViewController.m

Ok.It works now.

(P.S where the default png files come from ... ? :-( )